# CodeSign Error while preparing App for distribution using Distribution certificate

Tags: iphone

I have created a Distribution certificate, & a Distribution Provisioning Profile for Ad-Hoc Distribution/ AppStore submission. I have made all the necessary changes in Info.plist, Entitlements file, Targets -> Build of the project. I'm getting an error. i've attached screen shot of this error.[image]

This error seems to be occurring coz I've no profiles currently matching for iphone distribution[image: .].
It displays 'profile doesn't match any valid certificate/ private key pair in default keychain'.
I've checked the certificate & its valid.
**Can there be some issue with the private key present in the keychain access. If so the case, please suggest a solution.**

Comment: If there is other system where these profiles are working then delete all the certificates and provisioning profiles from your system and import from the working system. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are unable to get the private key you are going to have to re-generate one. This will not affect in any way whatsoever already published applications, but will invalidate your current distribution certificate and provisioning profiles.

So, the steps you need to take are:

1. Log in to the provisioning portal
2. Go to Certificates, switch to Distribution tab
3. Revoke the current certificate
4. Open up Keychain Access on your Mac and create a new certificate signing request (plenty of resources on how to do that)
5. Upload the CSR to the provisioning portal, wait for the server to process it
6. Download the newly created certificate and install it (double click)
7. Go to Provisioning, switch to distribution tab
8. Generate your provisioning profile for AdHoc distribution, download it and install it

You can now use it to sign your application.

This would be an excellent time for you to backup your newly generated certificate. In Keychain Access go to Keys, right click your newly generated private key and export it as a p12 file. Store it somewhere safe.

Comment: after downloading newly created certificate & installing it does it create the private key in the key chain access?

Comment: Steps #4 and #6 create a new certificate-private key pair. When you install the certificate the private key should show up in the Keys section. Make sure you are on the *login* keychain.

Comment: i followed #4 and #6, but still facing the same prob.i am using my agents credentials to download the certificates from portal to my mac machine. she created a distribution profile on a different machine which is not available now. does it matter , is  it necessary that i should obtain the private key of my agents machine.

Comment: If the machine is no longer available you are going to have to revoke the existing certificates and follow all the steps I mentioned above. The private key cannot be restored or replaced if you don't have it, you need to create a new one and a new set of certificates.

Comment: tnx  just now i completed the loading successfully. but my app is crashing during the launch and the debugger is showing errors. my app is a reader and when i placed 6 books in the resources after crashing if i open the app in device only 5 books are being loaded. what might be the reason for the crash and incomplete loading

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the private key of the certificate present in your keychain. It is generally present on the system where the CSR(Certificate Signing Request) for the certificate is created first. If you have transferred the certificate from a different system, try exporting the private key as .p12 file(Identity export), rather than exporting the certificate alone.

Comment: How to go about if i dont have the private key as back up?

Comment: Private key is a must to sign your application

Comment: if i create a new CSR will a new private key be generated along with it.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the most suitable solution now, since you don't have the access to the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "Distribution Certificate" and not "Development Certificate"
This you can get from provisioning portal under Certificates > Distribution.

Once you have added the certificate to the portal, download and add it to your keyChain.

Also make sure that you made the provision file under "Distribution Provisioning Profile"
this can be done under provisioning>Distribution

Comment: I have the Distribution provisioning profile. After adding the Dist. provisioning profile to key chain i'm unable get the private key. Any further suggestions?